# Angular (^16.0.0) Material (^16.1.0) Datepicker label is floating too high

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I'm trying to include a `mat-datepicker` in an Angular page but the label is floating too high, so when I make a date choice, the label actually gets pushed up under the top bar on the page. No idea what I'm doing wrong; halp.

Am I missing something in my app's .scss file?  Do I need to import something else?

Here's the undesired behavior:

**Before:**

[image: Before I pick a date]

**After:**

[image: After I pick a date]

You can see the label pushed up under my app's top bar.  I feel like it's because the label starts too high.

If I highlight it with dev tools, it looks like this:

[image: Highlighted with browser dev tools]

`app.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatMenuModule } from "@angular/material/menu";
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import { MatDatepickerModule } from "@angular/material/datepicker";
import { MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { JournalEditorComponent } from './journal-editor/journal-editor.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    JournalEditorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, 
    MatInputModule, 
    MatDatepickerModule, 
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`styles.scss`:

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

// Define a dark theme
$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
 color: (
   primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-blue-palette),
   accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$orange-palette),
 ),
  // Only include `typography` and `density` in the default dark theme.
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(  ),
  density: 0,
));

// Define a light theme
$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$light-blue-palette),
   accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$orange-palette),
 ),
));

// Apply the dark theme by default
@include mat.core-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.button-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.slide-toggle-theme( $dark-theme);
@include mat.toolbar-theme( $dark-theme);
@include mat.menu-theme( $dark-theme);
@include mat.icon-theme( $dark-theme);
@include mat.sidenav-theme( $dark-theme);
@include mat.datepicker-theme( $dark-theme);

// Apply the light theme only when the user prefers light themes.
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
 // Use the `-color` mixins to only apply color styles without reapplying the same
 // typography and density styles.
 @include mat.core-color($light-theme);
 @include mat.button-color($light-theme);
 @include mat.slide-toggle-color( $light-theme);
 @include mat.toolbar-color( $light-theme);
 @include mat.menu-color( $light-theme);
 @include mat.icon-color( $light-theme);
 @include mat.sidenav-color( $light-theme);
 @include mat.datepicker-color( $light-theme);
 }

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

`component.html`:

```html
<div id="daterow">
   <span class="spacer"></span>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
        <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

`component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-journal-editor',
  templateUrl: './journal-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./journal-editor.component.scss']
})
export class JournalEditorComponent {

}
```

`component.scss`:

```scss
#daterow {
    display: flex;

    .spacer {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Need to add the following to my `styles.scss`:

```scss
@include mat.form-field-theme($dark-theme);
@include mat.input-theme($dark-theme);
```

(and likewise for the `*-color( $light-theme)` bit a little later in the file.)

Found this out by noticing the examples use `@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);`, so I wondered what `all-component-themes` includes that I wasn't.  Tracked it down in the github repo and voilà!